# How to add a custom "global" search bar in react material table where the default search bar appears?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

**This is my code for the material table. I need to add a custom search bar(dynamic) instead of the default search bar. And I need to add it in the same place where the default search bar of material table appears.**

Please answer if anyone know a solution.

Thank you!

```
function EmployeeTable() {
            
  return (
         <div className={classes.tableContainer}>
            <MaterialTable className="transparent-table"
              icons={tableIcons} 
              columns={columns} 
              data={tableData}
              
              options={
                {
                  search:false, 
                  exportButton:true,
                  exportAllData:true
                }
              } 
            />
         </div>
  )
}
```

**I tried this but it didn't work.**

```
function EmployeeTable() {

    const handleSearch = (searchText) => {
         //search logic
    }

    const CustomSearch = ({ onSearch }) => {
      const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("")

      const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
          onSearch(searchText);
        }
      }

      return (
        <input
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(event) => setSearchText(event.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        />
      )
    }

  return (
            <MaterialTable className="transparent-table"
              icons={tableIcons} 
              columns={columns} 
              data={tableData}

              components={{
                Toolbar: (props) => (
                  <div>
                    <div style={{ display: "flex"}}>
                      <CustomSearch onSearch={props.onSearch} />
                    </div>
                    <props.components.Toolbar {...props} />
                  </div>
                ),
              }}
              onSearchChanged={handleSearch}
              
              options={
                {
                  search:false, 
                  exportButton:true,
                  exportAllData:true
                }
              }  
            />
  )
}
```